# How to dynamically add or delete tasks to celery without restarting celery

Tags: python-2.7, celery

Add or delete tasks to celery through the management side, do not restart celery, how to let celery perform newly added tasks. How should I do it, thank you very much for helping me.

Celery version is 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Celery does not provide API to do this for a good reason - it is extremely hard to do right. What if your task needs few extra dependencies and one of them needs a shared library installed on the system? What if it needs to be built from the source?

As a matter of fact, there is no distributed system that does this that I know of (if someone does, please enlighten me). Instead, nowadays it is very easy to replace all workers with new ones that have one or more tasks removed/added using Docker containers for an example.